# Mahout - TestForest fails to calculate the final analysis ( confusion matrix, accuracy, kappa, etc)

Tags: garbage-collection, mahout, random-forest

I am currently trying to classify data with the partial implementation of the randomforest in Mahout.

While i was able to classify certain amounts of data with a fix set of trained forests, i am not able to do so with larger data (about twice as large) and the same classifiers.

In fact, the classification which is done during MR is working fine and showed to be successful. Sadly, when the analysis shall be calculated, it always ends up in an OutOfMemoryException which may have occurred due to the reached GCOverheadLimit. I also added the option:

-Dmapred.child.java.opts="-Xmx20g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"

to the call, but it did not help.

I can remember times, when i was using an earlier version of mahout (i think it was 0.7) which could classify nearly arbitrarily large datasets with the testforest method and also output the analysis measures such as the confusion matrix etc. I am confused why the easiest step in the whole process leads to such errors.

Is there a way to fix this easily?

Here is one of the logs:

```
15/05/25 13:58:26 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 97% reduce 0%
15/05/25 13:58:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 98% reduce 0%
15/05/25 13:59:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 99% reduce 0%
15/05/25 14:01:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/05/25 14:02:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1432549186261_0032 completed successfully
15/05/25 14:02:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 33
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=2202834240
        FILE: Number of bytes written=3408230
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=580537741
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=343262060
        HDFS: Number of read operations=150
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=60
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=9
        Launched map tasks=39
        Other local map tasks=19
        Data-local map tasks=17
        Rack-local map tasks=3
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=3387270
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=3387270
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=3387270
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=10405693440
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=16993025
        Map output records=16993045
        Input split bytes=4950
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=15935
        CPU time spent (ms)=1798740
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=27353509888
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=102048583680
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=58348666880
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=580532791
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=343262060
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.Classifier.parseOutput(Classifier.java:169)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.Classifier.run(Classifier.java:130)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.TestForest.mapreduce(TestForest.java:188)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.TestForest.testForest(TestForest.java:174)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.TestForest.run(TestForest.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.mapreduce.TestForest.main(TestForest.java:315)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:153)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found the solution, although it is unclear to me why it works:

Adding ...

`export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx20192m"`

... to the script did the trick.

Using `MAHOUT_HEAPSIZE=40000` or `-Dmapred.child.java.opts` did not help.

I found the inspiration for the solution here: 
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Data-Science-and-Machine/Java-heap-size-running-mahout-clusterdump/td-p/7752

If you got similar problems, you might be interested in setting the variables which can be found in the mahout script which is also available online:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/bin/mahout